# Overload Function with List as a Parameter

Tags: c#, .net, list, generics, overloading

I want to create a function with C# List datatype as a parameter.

```
public void foo(List<Something> obj)
{
...
}
```

But I want to pass anykind of List type to the function, I mean, like this

```
List<Class1> obj1 = new List<Class1>();
foo(obj1);

List<Class2> obj2 = new List<Class2>();
foo(obj2);
```

Can I do something like this? How to do this? Thanks in advance

Comment: [Generic methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb(v=vs.80).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

```
public void foo<T>(List<T> obj)
{
...
}
```

call like

```
 foo<Class1>(new List<Class1>());
 foo<Class2>(new List<Class2>());
```

The above can be simplified further to by making use of [generics type inference](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/08/06/making-the-most-of-generic-type-inference.aspx)

```
 foo(new List<Class1>());
 foo(new List<Class2>());
```

Comment: Note that type inference will take care of the type argument here, so you can call just `foo(new List<Class1>())`

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware about type inference. Just going through the your [blog](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/08/06/making-the-most-of-generic-type-inference.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Add a generic argument to your `foo` method.

```
public void foo<T>(List<T> obj)
{
...
}
```

You can find more about them [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).